# How to fix "right syntax to use near ' as begin" error in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a simple stored procedure but getting the error "right syntax to use near ' as begin select Fname from employee2 end". I am not able to understand what is the error as it is the same syntax that i found on various websites online. I tried both the below syntaxes but getting same error.

```
create procedure sp_get as 
begin
select Fname from employee2
end;
```

```
create procedure sp_get as
select Fname from employee2
go;
```

Comment: It looks like you are using code samples/websites for mssql. Make sure to include "mysql" in your searches.

Comment: Is stored procedure not supported in latest versions of mysql ?

Comment: Stored procedures are supported. But the (exact) [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) differs between mssql and mysql (and others). (e.g. non-optional brackets, no "as", no "go", you cannot leave out the `;` after your select statement, ....). You are just using the wrong website. And also make sure that you specify the correct database system - the error message in your other comment, "statement is incomplete, please check the syntax at line 4" neither belongs to mssql nor mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
  create procedure sp_get() 
  begin
      select Fname from employee2
  end
```

Comment: No it's showing error "statement is incomplete, please check the syntax at line 4"